# Why doesn´t Grover's Algorithm work for my Qiskit circuit?

Tags: qiskit, grovers-algorithm

I built a circuit in Qiskit with two GHZ states. In the beginning, I created the superposition $\sim\bigg(|0000\rangle+|0101\rangle+|1010\rangle+|1111\rangle\bigg)$ with two $H$s, and two $CNOT$s.

Now, I want to amplify the result $|1111\rangle$ to over $50\%$. The maximum I got was around $40\%$, and for this case, I calculated that I needed only one iteration. I also tried more, but with no success.

Edit: Can anyone tell me how to implement Amplitude Amplification without needing to apply state initialization operator and the inverse of it because the state initialization operator could be highly complex?

[image: Circuit]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Grover algorithm to work, the initial state must be a uniform superposition of all the states. Since your initial state is different, Grover algorithm will not work. Instead, you should use its generalization, [Amplitude Amplification](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stable/0.26/tutorials/algorithms/07_grover.html).

In amplitude amplification, the Grover operator $\mathcal{Q}$ is
$$\mathcal{Q} = \mathcal{A}\mathcal{S_0}\mathcal{A}^\dagger \mathcal{S_f}$$
where $\mathcal{A}$ is the initial state, $\mathcal{S_0}$ is the reflection about all zero state, and $\mathcal{S_f}$ is the oracle.
So, you circuit should look like:

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to implement Amplitude Amplification without having to apply the initial state and the inverse of the initial state, for the case that the state initialization algorithm is highly complex.